# How do I sum values in array from certain indexes in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to sum values from the array from certain ranges provided by another array.

I've tried with this function

```
function sumArray($array, $min, $max) {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
       if ($k >= $min && $k <= $max) {
          $sum += $v;
       }
    }
    return $sum;
 }
```

and this works if i hardcode numbers of course, but i can't figure out how to make this work in a loop

So I have this dates array

```
array(3) {
  ["June"]=> int(4)
  ["July"]=> int(31)
  ["August"]=> int(29)
}
```

and i have this daily_values array

```
array(64) {
  [0]=> int(8)
  [1]=> int(6)
  [2]=> int(10)
  [3]=> int(15)
  [4]=> int(10)
  [5]=> int(9)
  [6]=> int(9)
  .
  .
  .
  [63] => int(10)
```

Now what I want to do here is:
based on how many entries are in for example June which is 4 in this case I want to get the sum of values in daily_values array like this:

first loop iteration will sum values in daily_values array from 0 to 3, the second loop iteration will sum values from 4 to 34 and third loop iteration will sum values from 35 to 63 and so on and so on.

So the final thing I want from all this is to have an array which will be like this

`["sum of 0,3", "sum of 4,34", "sum of 35,63"]`

Just a note here, this array is much bigger, but I cut it short just for question purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to understand your question and here is what I think you are trying to achieve.
I created a similar test and it works fine. Hope it helps you in someway.

```
<?php

$june = [1,1,1,1];
$july = [1,1];
$august = [1,1,1,1];

$months = array(
    'June' => $june, 
    'July' => $july, 
    'August' => $august, 
);

$daily = [1,1,1,1,5,5,10,10,10,10,2,2,2,2,2];
$sum_arr = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($months as $key=>$month){

    $month_count = $month;
    $month_sum = 0;
    while($month_count > 0){
        $month_sum += $daily[$i];
        $i++;
        $month_count--;
    }
    $sum_arr[$key] = $month_sum;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($sum_arr);

?>
```

Comment: Hello Omar, thank you so much! Just 1 change i made in order for it to work is instead of count($month) i just had to put $month, and it worked perfectly.